# How to register a class in the provider and pass in constructor dependencies later

Tags: php, laravel, oop, dependency-injection

Consider the following class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Game\Battle\Services;

use App\Flare\Models\Character;
use App\Game\Battle\Values\LevelUpValue;

class CharacterService {

    private $character;

    public __construct(Character $character) {
        $this->character = $character;
    }

    public function levelUpCharacter() {
        $this->character->update(resolve(LevelUpValue::class)->getLevelAttributes());
    }
}
```

I would like to register this in a provider and then when I resolve it, then pass in the `Character` param.

Now I know how to register classes, but I dont know how to register them such that when I resolve them I can pass in my own params.

I normally register my classes as `singleton` (except in some cases where I just use `bind`), but heres an example:

```
    $this->app->singleton(BaseStatValue::class, function ($app) {
        return new BaseStatValue();
    });
```

So I know I can do:

```
    $this->app->singleton(CharacterService::class, function ($app) {
        return new CharacterService();
    });
```

But how do I now resolve it with me physically passing it, the dependencies? I do not want a bunch of `new CharacterService($character)` in my code, I want to retrieve `Character` from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not resolve Dependencies later but You can build `Character` in `CharacterService` signleton closure:

```
$this->app->singleton(CharacterService::class, function ($app) {
    return new CharacterService($app->make(Character::class));
});
```

BTW. Try to avoid signleton becouse they are hard to test